# want to retrieve blackberry messenger contacts category wise

Tags: blackberry

new on blackberry messenger api, I want to retrieve the blackberry messenger contacts category wise, and want to broadcast particular message to the selected categories through blackberry messenger.(working with JDE_sdk-5.0)

can anybody help me to know how to retrieve the contacts from blackberry messenger application
category wise?

Comment: Hi @Jitendrakumarjha, what do you mean by BBM contact category? Is it something project-specific?

Comment: Hi @Max Gontar In BBM you have BBM group(different categories) of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [BB Messenger SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/):

1. read [Getting Started Guide - BlackBerry Messenger SDK - 1.3](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36641/),
   especially requirements part
2. use [BBMPlatformContactList.getAll()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/bbm/1.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/bbm/platform/profile/BBMPlatformContactList.html#getAll%28%29) to retrieve all
   messenger contacts
3. choose you way to [interact with contacts](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Interacting_with_contacts_1448256_11.jsp)

then, if you want to broadcast message within several contacts, you can try to:

1. [host public session](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Host_a_BBM_session_1512041_11.jsp)
2. [invite contacts to your session](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Send_a_session_invite_1509672_11.jsp)
3. [broarcast a message to all participants](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Send_a_msg_to_all_contacts_in_a_session_1523927_11.jsp)

**UPDATE**
In BB Messenger SDK v. 1.3 (beta), in class [BBMPlatformContact](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/bbm/1.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/bbm/platform/profile/BBMPlatformContact.html) which represents BBM contact, as well as in class [BBMPlatformContactList](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/bbm/1.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/bbm/platform/profile/BBMPlatformContactList.html) there is no way to access BBM contact groups or categiries. Seems like it's not possible in current version.

Comment: hi, thanks for responding, I am already involved at bbm platform api,

I am specific to retrieve the contacts category-wise.

so please let me know if u have relevant information.